ASP.Net Core Web project not finding referenced appsettings
We have a microservice architecture where most services use the Microsoft.NET.Sdk. Since we have many shared configurations, we have a library that preconfigures each service with a global-appsettings.json. This configuration works great since we copy that global configuration file to the output directory. However, now we have a service that requires the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web SDK. For some reason, this service does not look for the app settings in the output directory; instead, it only looks for them in the source directory. I have tried various things to try and pinpoint the problem, but I have not figured out a solution:

When changing the SDK of the new service to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web, the global-appsettings.json is found without any other changes. (This was just to test this and is not a viable solution)

When copying the global-appsettings.json to the source of the new service, it also works, but this is also suboptimal as we do not want to maintain two identical files and destroy the benefits of them

Adding a link via the following property did not work, meaning the service did not find the file:
<Content Include="..\..\..\shared\Rapidata.Shared.Configuration\global-appsettings.Development.json">
  <Link>global-appsettings.Development.json</Link>
</Content>



So, how can I reference a settings file from a shared library when using the Web SDK?

You need to copy the file to required location and use SetBasePath in code

According to your description, I suggest you could use
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile method to set the right path with the global-appsettings.json and then it could get it.
According to the config you have shared, it seems the global-appsettings.Development.json file is inside the parent folder for the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web project.
I suggest you could use Directory.GetParent(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath).FullName to get the current application's parent path , and then use the Path.Combine method to build the full path. At last use the right path to set the configuration file.
More details, you could refer to below example:
Please notice: My testing file is just inside application's root parent path, you could call the Directory.GetParent again to get the parent path's parent path.
var sharedConfigPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath).FullName, "Rapidata.Shared.Configuration");
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(sharedConfigPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
var test = builder.Configuration["test"];

Result:

